# How can I pass an array of structures to a function by reference?

Tags: c, function, structure, pass-by-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeValues(struct ITEM *item[]);

struct ITEM
{
int number;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct ITEM items[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items[i].number = i;//initialize
        printf("BEFORE:: %d\n", items[i].number);
    }

    changeValues(items);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items[i].number = i;
        printf("AFTER:: %d\n", items[i].number);
    }

    return 0;
}

void changeValues(struct ITEM *item[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    item[i] -> number += 5;
}
```

I am trying to pass an array of structures to a function. I need to change the values of the structures members within the function by reference and not value. For some odd reason when I print the results after the function is called the values remain the same as they were prior to the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you can't pass by reference (like C++). You can only pass by value, or pass by pointer.

In this case, it appears that you want to pass an array of struct to function `changeValues`. That's what you do in `main`. However, the prototype and implementation of `changeValues` you actually try to pass an array of pointer to struct `ITEM`.

One possible fix is to change the array of pointer to struct `ITEM` to just array of struct.

```
void changeValues(struct ITEM item[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        item[i].number += 5;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: You actually had two other mistakes in your code:

1) The definition of struct `ITEM` need to be before `changeValues` prototype:

```
struct ITEM
{
    int number;
};

void changeValues(struct ITEM item[]);
```

2) In your `main()` you actually reset all value in `changeValues` - basically you invalidated everything done in that function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    items[i].number = i;   // <-- Remove this line as you are resetting the value again here
    printf("AFTER:: %d\n", items[i].number);
}
```

---

```
struct ITEM
{
    int number;
};

void changeValues(struct ITEM item[]);


int main(void)
{
    struct ITEM items[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items[i].number = i;//initialize
        printf("BEFORE:: %d\n", items[i].number);
    }

    changeValues(items);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // items[i].number = i;   // <-- Remove this line as you are resetting the value again here
        printf("AFTER:: %d\n", items[i].number);
    }

    return 0;
}

void changeValues(struct ITEM items[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items[i].number += 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: when calling the function in my main would it look like "changeValues(item);" ?

Comment: Thank you. Best answer. My program is working and I submitted my assignment on time.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'pass as reference' by passing the pointer address.

Here is an example:

```
int main(void)
{

    char *pA;     /* a pointer to type character */
    char *pB;     /* another pointer to type character */
    puts(strA);   /* show string A */
    pA = strA;    /* point pA at string A */
    puts(pA);     /* show what pA is pointing to */
    pB = strB;    /* point pB at string B */
    putchar('\n');       /* move down one line on the screen */
    while(*pA != '\0')   /* line A (see text) */
    {
        *pB++ = *pA++;   /* line B (see text) */
    }
    *pB = '\0';          /* line C (see text) */
    puts(strB);          /* show strB on screen */
    return 0;
}
```